# Vector c типом класс с++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Пытаюсь сделать вектор с типом класса MyClass. Почему функции v.size() и v.capacity() работают нормально, а v.pop_back() и v.front() не работают?
Не выводит ничего после запуска программы.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass(int x = 1) : xp(x) {}

int x() const { return xp; }
private:
int xp;
};

int main()
{

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
vector<MyClass> v {7, 9, 8};
cout << "\n\tВектор с пользовательским типом данных";
cout << "\n\tСодержимое вектора: "; 
for (const auto& f : v) {
    cout << f.x() << std::endl;
}
cout << "\tsize(): " << v.size() << endl;
cout << "\tcapacity(): " << v.capacity() << endl;
cout << "\n\tЭлемент с индексом 1 - > " << endl;
v.pop_back();
cout << "\n\tПервый элемент в векторе: " << endl;
v.front();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция **pop_back** удаляет элемент молча, и ничего не возращает. А функция **front** возвращает ссылку на первый элемент. Стиль языка C : нет просьбы что-то напечатать, не буду.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
cout << "\n\tЭлемент с индексом 1 - > " << v[1] << endl;
cout << "\n\tПервый элемент в векторе: " << v.front() << endl;
```